# How do i solve ruby grpc health check NOTFOUND error?

Tags: ruby, grpc

I am getting this error when perform following for health check:

```
require 'grpc/health/v1/health_pb'
require 'grpc/health/checker'

class HealthCheckService < Grpc::Health::V1::Health::Service
  def check(req, req_view)
    checker = Grpc::Health::Checker.new
    checker.check(req, req_view)
  end
end
```

Error is:

> GRPC::NotFound:5:unknown cause.

Anyone has faced this issue before. really would appreciate for help.

Comment: Obviously some resource is not found here. Might be a misconfiguration etc.

Comment: How we pass service here. I have passed by: Grpc::Health::V1::HealthCheckRequest.new(service: 'Hotels'). Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed `grpc` and `gprc-tools`?

```sh
gem install grpc
gem install grpc-tools
```

I'm entirely unfamiliar with Ruby but familiar with gRPC.

Your code (with a tweak) works for me:

```rb
require 'grpc/health/v1/health_pb'
require 'grpc/health/checker'

class HealthCheckService < Grpc::Health::V1::Health::Service
  def check(req, req_view)
    checker = Grpc::Health::Checker.new
    checker.set_status_for_services(
        Grpc::Health::V1::HealthCheckResponse::ServingStatus::SERVING,
        "foo",
        "bar"
      )
    checker.check(req, req_view)
  end
end

def main
  s = GRPC::RpcServer.new
  s.add_http2_port("0.0.0.0:50051",:this_port_is_insecure)
  s.handle(HealthCheckService)
  s.run_till_terminated_or_interrupted([1,"int","SIGQUIT"])
end

main
```

And then, downloading [`health.proto`](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/proto/grpc/health/v1/health.proto), I can:

```sh
for SERVICE in "foo" "bar" "baz"
do
  grpcurl \
  -plaintext \
  --proto health.proto \
  -d "{\"service\":\"${SERVICE}\"}" \
  localhost:50051 \
  grpc.health.v1.Health/Check
{
  "status": "SERVING"
}
{
  "status": "SERVING"
}
ERROR:
  Code: NotFound
  Message: unknown cause
```